# why null goes as this is true in statement in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello guys I was wondering anyone knows why this pl/sql code give a result false but I was excpeting the result will be raise exception but I didn't get it why like that nvl protect us from null value as I know.

```
declare
i_send_type varchar2(100) := null;
begin
    if nvl(i_send_type,'') <> 'cash' and nvl(i_send_type,'') <> 'card'  then
      raise_application_error(-20032,'o_userMessage');
  end if; 
end;
```

Comment: To add to Littlefoot's answer, in Oracle (unless you explicitly exclude null values), boolean logic is actually tri-valued logic: TRUE, FALSE, or NULL. In your example above, the result of your `IF` statement when `i_send_type` is null, then the result will be NULL, not TRUE or FALSE. If it helps, try thinking  UNKNOWN when you come across `NULL` in `IF` statements and other logic, e.g. "Is NULL equal to <a specific value>" becomes "Is this unknown value equal to <a specific value>"? It's unknown!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why this pl/sql code give a result false

It does not. It gives a result as not true.

Not true is only the same as false in binary logic where there are two possible values, true or false. In databases (and not just Oracle), they use trinary logic and can have the values: true, false or unknown (`NULL`).

For example, if you compare the `=` operator:

| = | x | y | NULL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **x** | TRUE | FALSE | NULL |
| **y** | FALSE | TRUE | NULL |
| **NULL** | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Then `NULL = <anything>` or `<anything> = NULL` always gives the result `NULL` (and not false) because you cannot tell if an unknown is equal to anything else (even another unknown) as the values are unknown.

For the `<>` operator, the logic is similar to above with `TRUE` and `FALSE` swapped in the output but the result is still `NULL` (and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`) when either input is `NULL`.

---

In Oracle, the empty string `''` is identical to `NULL` so `nvl(i_send_type,'')` is the same as `nvl(i_send_type,NULL)` which is the same as `i_send_type` so you end up with the comparisons `NULL <> 'cash' OR NULL <> 'card'` which results in `NULL` (and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`).

---

To solve it, you can reverse the operator and use `=` or `IN` and then use an `ELSE` condition:

```sql
DECLARE
  i_send_type varchar2(100) := null;
BEGIN
  IF i_send_type IN ('cash', 'card') THEN
    -- Do nothing
    NULL;
  ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20032,'o_userMessage');
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

or, if you want to get rid of the `ELSE` then you have to explicitly check for `NULL` values using `IS NULL`:

```sql
DECLARE
  i_send_type varchar2(100) := null;
BEGIN
  IF i_send_type IS NULL OR i_send_type NOT IN ('cash', 'card') THEN
    raise_application_error(-20032,'o_userMessage');
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because an empty string - in Oracle - is *equivalent* of `NULL`, which means that `NVL` actually did nothing; it said

> if `i_send_type` is `NULL`, then take empty string (i.e. `NULL` again) instead

In that case, you compared `NULL` to `'cash'` and `'card'` using `<>`, but `NULL` can't be compared that way - you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

---

So, what to do?

One option: don't use empty string in `NVL` but e.g. `'x'` (or some other string that can't be contents of `i_send_type`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    i_send_type varchar2(100) := null;
  3  begin
  4      if nvl(i_send_type,'x') <> 'cash' and nvl(i_send_type,'x') <> 'card'  then
  5        raise_application_error(-20032,'o_userMessage');
  6      end if;
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20032: o_userMessage
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

---

Another (better) option: check - as I said - whether variable's value `IS NULL`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    i_send_type varchar2(100) := null;
  3  begin
  4      if i_send_type not in ('cash', 'card') or i_send_type is null then
  5        raise_application_error(-20032,'o_userMessage');
  6      end if;
  7  end;
  8  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20032: o_userMessage
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```